# DB2 Bulk Load from .Net (C#)?

Tags: c#, .net, db2

Is there an API for loading a large # of non-transactional rows directly into a DB2 table?

I know there are some CLI commands for doing this, but it isn't clear what is directly supported from the .Net APIs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the ADMIN_CMD stored procedure, which gives SQL applications access to the LOAD utility and many other administrative commands. Here's the relevant info for DB2 9.5: http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9r5/topic/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.rtn.doc/doc/r0023577.html